# Como ordenar uma div por um atributo string com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, classificação

Estou a desenvolver uma lista que tem o cabeçalho "ID" e "Status" e o seus valores de ID e de Status,eu tambem defini um input do tipo hidden para ação.

Segue exemplo:

```
<div class="cabecalho">
   <div><span id="orderID">ID</span></div>
   <div><span id="orderStatus">Status</span></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
   <div class="listStatus" status="f" contagem="1">
      <div>1<div>
      <div>F<div>
   </div>

   <div class="listStatus" status="C" contagem="2">
      <div>2<div>
      <div>C<div>
   </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="acao" value="asc"/>
```

Então, para que a ordenação funcione, escrevi o seguinte código.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orderStatus").click(function(){
        var acao = $('#acao').val();
        var statusList = $(".listStatus");
        statusList.sort();
        if(acao=="desc"){
           $('#acao').val('asc');
           statusList.reverse();
        }
        else{
           $('#acao').val('desc');
        }
        $('#container').html(statusList);
    });
 });
```

Só que o console de erros do JS está exibindo o seguinte erro: "statusList.reverse is not a function".

Além disso, a ordenação 'ASC' não está funcionando.

**Atualização:**

Consegui da seguinte maneira, era mais simples do que eu esperava,
o HTML continua o mesmo, somente o JavaScript mudou, vou deixar abaixo o código para que outras pessoas possam utilizar.

Segue código:

```
$("#orderStatus").click(function(){
    var acao = $('#acao').val();
    var statusList = $(".listStatus");
    statusList.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(acao == "asc"){
            $('#acao').val('desc');
            return $(b).attr("status") > $(a).attr("status");
        }
        else{
            $('#acao').val('asc');
            return $(a).attr("status") > $(b).attr("status");
        }
    });
    $('#container').html(statusList);
});
```

Comment: eu acho que o reverse(); so funciona com array.

Comment: Realmente não funcionava, a ordenação em ordem alfabetica é parecida com a de numeros, somente o sinal muda de "-" para ">". Valeu pela dica!!

Comment: desculpe não apresentar uma resposta mas não tive o tempo para da uma googada ou estudar sobre.

Comment: @JasarOrion, isso mesmo, a função `reverse()` existe somente para array.

Comment: Cai numa outra situação, quando vou fazer a lista eu faço uma verificação, para montar a lista... se i mod 2 = 0 cor  de fundo = FFF, se não cor de fundo DCDCDC...
Então, quando eu clico para fazer a ordenação, as cores ordenam junto, deixando as cores agrupadas, o que na verdade deveria ser com sim, cor não para facilitar a visualização da linha inteira. Não estou conseguindo alterar o CSS da div para que fique nesse formato, tem como fazer isso nessa mesma função eu terei que fazer outra?

Comment: @BrunoFolle, boa tarde.
Coloque a resolução como resposta da sua própria pergunta. (Já que foi resolvido)

Comment: Talvez a resposta dessa pergunta possa ajudá-lo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945484/how-to-sort-html-elements-according-to-array-values